# Select a webelement that contains specific text

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have multiple elements with the same resource-id (they are all not on screen at the same time), so I need to be able to select them based off of the text they contain. However, part of the text will occasionally change, and for each element only a small string of text will be constantly displayed. So, how can I go about selecting each element when I need to? I've tried:

Unfortunately, it returns a bool value, and so I cannot 'click' it:

```
    get_code = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "android:id/big_text"), 'validation'))
    element.click()
```

This usually works for me, but I need to include contains(text(), 'validation') and I have not been able to find a way to do this:

```
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "android:id/big_text")))
    element.click()
```

Maybe something like this would work?

```
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="android:id/big_text" and contains(text(), "validation"]')))
    element.click()
```

But I am not sure how to format it. Any other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets in last try are wrong, try with:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="android:id/big_text" and contains(text(), "validation")]'))
element.click()
```

Comment: EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="android:id/big_text" and contains(text(), "validation")]'))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Why doesn't this work :             element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'validation')]")))
            element.click()    The element is just not clicked, no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "android:id/big_text")))
        element[0].click()
```

Works sufficiently well, for now...Open to better options.

Comment: You can always try xpath which is the best option amongst other locator. You can check xpath mentioned in my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. It should work. The implementation of text() in xpath of appium client is little different than selenium for browsers.

```
EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='android:id/big_text' and contains(@text, 'validation')]")
```

OR

```
EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="android:id/big_text" and contains(@text, "validation")]')
```

The different between above two xpath's is just type of quotations used.

Comment: No luck. Both threw 'takes 2 arguments (3 given).' I resolved this by adding another set of parenthesis, but then no action was taken (nothing was actually clicked)...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("text")
```

or this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("text")
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('part_of_text')
```